# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x_0∈X$ be a limit point of $X-{x_0}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $x_0∈X$ be a limit point of $X-{x_0}$. Direct the set $X-{x_0}$ by the relation $x ≤ x'$ if $d(x',x_ 0)≤ d(x,x_0)$. Show that a net $ϕ:X-{x_0} \rightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is a metric space, converges to $y_0∈ Y$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to x_0} ϕ (x)=y_0$.

When I write the definition of the limit for metric spaces, I realize that the $\delta$ controls the directed set and the net controls the $\epsilon$, but I am not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll do one direction to get you started.

Suppose that $\varphi$ converges to $y_0$, and let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is an $x_\epsilon\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$ such that $d_Y(\varphi(x),y_0)<\epsilon$ whenever $x\in X\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $x_\epsilon\le x$, i.e., whenever $x\in  X\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $d_X(x,x_0)\le d_X(x_\epsilon,x_0)$. Take $\delta=d_X(x_\epsilon,x_0)$: if $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$, then $d_Y(\varphi(x),y_0)<\epsilon$, so $\lim_\limits{x\to x_0}\varphi(x)=y_0$.